# Changing Windows XP from one domain to another. How to preserve local user profile

Tags: windows-xp, domain, user-profile, migration

I have 5 XP machines, and 1 Windows 7 machine, on a domain. Each machine is used by individual users, and have their profile stored locally at "C:\Documents and Settings\user_name". I have to change these machines from one domain to the other, and I wan't to keep the profiles locally.
I need a procedure, and it can be a manual one since there are only 6 machine involved, that will preserve the user's profile intact, including CURRENT_USER registry and application data, so I can carry it over after I change the domain. I will apply this procedure one for every domain user of every machine that I will migrate
I tried several procedures, but none seen to work as a whole. The "Files and Settings Transfer wizard" for XP doesn't seem to copy everything, and the copy User Profile busts the profile after I copy from the local profile to the new domain user profile.
Appreciate any help or tips
Thanks

**Edit**

As far as the copy User Profile option, below are the steps I take:

- Copy domain user's profile to local user that already logged in once
- Migrate domain
- Login to migrated user, so it will create the profile dir
- Copy local user's profile to new domain's user

After I do that, and I log in to the new domain user, the profile was screwed up... It would save any of my setting and desktop changes

Comment: How does copying the profile bust it, exactly. I've done that a million times and never had problems with it. Are you specifiying that Everyone can use the  profile when you're copying it?

Comment: @joeqwerty I've edited the steps I took

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing Domain of a machine - any way to keep existing profile intact?](http://serverfault.com/questions/187806/changing-domain-of-a-machine-any-way-to-keep-existing-profile-intact)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[User Profile Wizard](http://www.forensit.com/downloads.html) should be able to take care of this for you.

Comment: Psychoholic, this tool is to migrate from one machine to another. I want to migrate to the same machine, and the same user, but for a differente domain

Comment: I was using the wrong tool. Transwiz was killer!

Comment: I've never used this tool to migrate to another machine...  I have however used it to enable a domain account to use the profile of a local account.  Works every time for me.  EDIT: I need to learn to read entire comments :(

Answer (score 0):

I've run into problems with copying user profiles (or pointing the registry entry to a different profile) due to permissions.  Assuming the users are not local admins, make sure they have full permissions on the CURRENT_USER registry hive.